# PHP How to push array into array[key]?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is the code I have:

```
$orders = Array();

foreach ($unassigned as $uorder) {
    $array = Array(
        "ordid"   => $uorder->idord,
        "fecha"   => $uorder->datorod,
        "cliente" => $uorder->idcli
    );

    array_push($orders[$uorder->user_id], $array);
}

print_r($orders);
```

Which results:

```
Array (
    [vendor1] => 
    [vendor2] => 
)
```

I want to make some kind of sort

So I could use `$orders[vendor1][0][ordid]` to find the first order that the vendor made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign `$orders[$uorder->user_id]` as an array first, otherwise it doesn't make sense to push an item onto it. Additionally, you can use the shorthand append notation:

```
if(!isset($orders[$uorder->user_id]))
    $orders[$uorder->user_id] = array();
$orders[$uorder->user_id][] = $array;
```

Comment: thank you very much it really help me a lot .... it was driving me crazy thanks so much !!!

Answer (score 0):

In your `foreach` loop check if `$orders[$uorder->user_id]` is an array, if not create one.

```
foreach($unassigned as $uorder):

    if(! is_array($orders[$uorder->user_id]))
        $orders[$uorder->user_id] = array();

    array_push($orders[$uorder->user_id],Array("ordid" => $uorder->idord, "fecha" =>  $uorder->datorod, "cliente" => $uorder->idcli));
endforeach;
```